# Как подсчитать часто встречающиеся числа?java

Tags: java

В задачке нужно получить k наиболее встречающихся чисел массива и вывести их долю в процентах. 
массив с рандомными числами ввела, а как дальше его сортировать понятия не имею( 
помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Можно использовать коллекции ? (списки и т.п.)

Comment: сказали, что здесь нужен только массив и циклы с условием, вроде как.
это курсовая первого семестра, очень мало прошли, поэтому вряд ли

Answer (score 2, accepted):

предположим у вас есть 2 массива:

```
int [] data = new data [50];  // массив хранит ваши значения
int [][] occurrences = new data [2][50];  // массив хранит количество вхождений каждого конкретного числа, где :
```

occurence[0] - хранит уникальное значение 
occurence[1] - хранит количество вхождений данного элемента в массив

далее в цикле по первому массиву подсчитываем количество вхождений каждого уникального элемента:
если элемента с таким значением во втором массиве 
а) нет - то добавляем его туда и устанавливаем значение в 1 (найден один раз)
б) есть - то увиличиваем счетчик на один

для обновления массива occurence вам понадобится счетчик который будет указывать на индекс последнего элемента напр. index (он нужен для того чтоб контролировать количество уникальных значений и добавлять новые элементы)

после этого надо найти значение с наибольшим количеством вхождений:
мне кажется что наиболее простой и интуитивно понятный спобоб здесь для новичка это сделать сортировку массива occurrences[1] (по количество вхождений), во время перестановки элементво occurences[1] делать соответствующие перестановки с элементами массива occurences[0];

после чего у вас в конце/начале массива (в зависимости от типа сортировки по убыванию/по возростанию ) будут нужные числа. вам надо будешь лишь вывести k последних/первых элементов.

не забудьте что во время сортировки вам надо будет сортировать только диапазон значений [0; index]

(p.s. предпочтительнее сортировать по убыванию)